# Java Difficulty communicating with an class object throught a Loop

Tags: java

I have a class named worker and a class called Pass which is the pass of the worker.
Im trying to built the main class in which all the processes are read from a text file.My code is full of loops and hopefully will work, but im having a problem.The first line of the text is plain text something like Worker: 1 worker1 , which simply means create a Worker object named worker1 and with passid (the id of his pass) number 1.This is do'able.However after this i simply put in the loop the creation of his pass.Which is my problem.
The 2n line of the text file gives my an AccessLog for the worker1 giving me a date of entry and exit.

```
    public static void main(String[ ] args) throws IOException {

  String file_name = "data.txt";

  try {
      FileRead file = new FileRead( file_name );
      String[ ] aryLines = file.Openfile();

      int i;
      for ( i=0; i < aryLines.length; i++ ) {
             String phrase = aryLines[i];
             String div = "[ ]+";
             String[] tokens = phrase.split(div);

             if (tokens[0].equals("Officer:")){

               if (tokens[1].equals("1")){

               Officer worker1 = new Worker("1","worker1",1);
               Pass worker1Pass = worker1.getPass();
               }


             //etc. for other workers                   
             }
```

Here comes the code for the access log and will explain the error

```
    else{
                 if (tokens[0].equals("AccessLog:")){

                  if (tokens[1].equals("1")){
                  String s1 = tokens[2] + tokens[3] ;
                  String s2 = tokens[4] + tokens[5] ;

                  try{
                      Date entry = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyHH:mm:ss").parse(s1);

                      Date exit = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyHH:mm:ss").parse(s2);
                      worker1Pass.workerEntry(entry);
                      worker1Pass.workerExit(exit);


                  }
                    catch (ParseException a) {
                       System.out.println( a.getMessage() );
                    }  
               }
```

workerentry and exit are methods in the pass class that log the access, and i get an error for missing symbol worker1pass.Also there seems to be a problem in the workerpass declaration because in netbeans there is a grey line beneath worker1pass calling it as an unused object.Lastly i would like to add that except the workaround code for the external text file the code works 100%.
Any tips and suggestions are welcome.

EDIT-------

```
    Worker worker1 = new Worker("1","worker1",1);
               Pass worker1Pass = worker1.getPass();
```

under worker1Pass im getting : variable worker1Pass is not used

```
                          worker1Pass.workerEntry(entry);
                  worker1Pass.workerExit(exit);
```

Here im getting cannot find symbol : worker1pass
Is like the pass worker1pass declaration does not declare a new pass as it should do and thus the methods don't add the entry and exit to the log as they should do.

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I'm having a tough time understanding what your problem is and what you're trying to do. If you don't get a decent solution soon, consider 1) writing out your problem a little more clearly using paragraphs to separate main ideas and using clear easily understood sentences. 2) Show any and all error messages that you may be seeing.

Comment: Are you supposed to be creating a collection of Worker or Pass objects? If so, where are these collections? Also, I've removed the [tag:netbeans] tag since your question really has nothing to do with netbeans.

Comment: Also consider showing some of your data file, enough so that we can better understand its structure.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels well yes, according to a txt file i should create Worker and Pass objects and add some logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the `missing symbol` error because `worker1Pass` was defined in the first `if` statement and is visible only in the if context. That is why netbeans is complaining too, because the `worker1Pass` in the first `if` is not visible (and not used) anywhere else. 
You should declare `worker1Pass` outside of your `if`, at least, to be visible in the second `if` statement too.

Like @HovercraftFullOfEels suggested, if you need to maintain all the `workers` and the `pass` objects you can use a [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) or a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), your code will look something like:

```
List<Officer> workers = new ArrayList<Officer>();
List<Pass> passes = new ArrayList<Pass>();
for ( i=0; i < aryLines.length; i++ ) { 
  String phrase = aryLines[i];
  String div = "[ ]+";
  String[] tokens = phrase.split(div);
  Officer worker = null; // and from this point on use this variable to represent a worker
  Pass workerPass = null; // used to represent a pass
  if (tokens[0].equals("Officer:")){
     if (tokens[1].equals("1")){
        worker = new Worker("1","worker1",1);
        workerPass = worker1.getPass();
        workers.add(worker); // add the worker in the workers list
        passes.add(workerPass); // add the pass in the passes list

     } 
     //etc. for other workers                   
  }
```

Comment: Well i would like all the declaration to be in a loop after the text scan.Dont know if im supposed to freely declare it without the text telling me to.

Comment: With this approach will the pass.method see the Pass object, or do i have to "point" it to the list.Because there will be if loops again. However thanx for the "new stuff"

Comment: @user1839880 Yes, if you will use: `workerPass.workerEntry(entry);` and `workerPass.workerExit(exit);`, instead of `worker1Pass` use the `for` visible `workerPass` object.

Comment: Think this was my problem.Thanx for the tips.Tell me one more thing, how does the list solve the problem? Is the list "visible" all the time by anyone?

Comment: @user1839880 You are welcome. The declaration of `Officer worker = null;` and `Pass workerPass = null;` are solving your issue. The list is needed only if you need to have access to all the workers and their passes, after the  file was processes (the loop has finished).

Comment: I see.Lists are good.However maybe i will have to make some changes to the code ,because initially there was no list for workers and passes plus there was no text file. And after the declarations there used to be some time calculations for every worker individually.

Comment: Sorry for bathering and chat here ,but what if i keep declaring every worker and pass by their name and then add them to the list?Do i have to keep the neutral names worker and workerpass instead of using worker1 2 etc.. Wont this be the same?

Comment: @user1839880 You can process each worker separately (probably is what you are already doing, because you mentioned `//etc. for other workers `) and user `worker1Pass`, the idea is to have the variable defined outside of `if`. But if you are doing the same thing to process a worker, the better approach would be to create a function that will know what to do, and call that function for each worker.